# Remove column names from resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to have the column names not shown on resultset. I have a 2 Sseperate SP's that are called on to get this result breakdown and these are emailed through sp-send-dbmail.

Below is what my results show

```
ID      Codes   TimeSUM Units   UPH Goal%   
--      -----   ------- -----   --- -----   
2427754 RC-SJ   7:15    1,696   234 104%    
2565466 RC-SJ   2:10    319     147  65%    
2413755 RC-SJ   2:00    182      91  40%    
2455    RC-SJ   2:30    91       36  16%    
ID      Codes   TimeSUM Units   UPH Goal%   
--      -----   ------- -----   --- -----   
22568   IC-RT   2:22    219 93  299%    
ID      Codes   TimeSUM Units   UPH Goal%   
--      -----   ------- -----   --- -----   
36593   IC-CC   5:22    2,689   501 121%    
22566   IC-CC   4:37    1,615   350  85%    
22567   IC-CC   1:06    0         0  0% 
22442   IC-CC   2:47    0         0  0%
```

I only want to see

```
2427754 RC-SJ   7:15    1,696   234 104%    
2565466 RC-SJ   2:10    319     147  65%    
2413755 RC-SJ   2:00    182      91  40%    
2455    RC-SJ   2:30    91       36  16%    

22568   IC-RT   2:22    219 93  299%    

36593   IC-CC   5:22    2,689   501 121%    
22566   IC-CC   4:37    1,615   350  85%    
22567   IC-CC   1:06    0         0  0% 
22442   IC-CC   2:47    0         0  0%
```

Comment: Hi @Sean Lange, I apologize if explained my question incorrectly. I am not familiar with what you recommended. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql), you can use:

```
@query_result_header=0
```

Comment: OH wow, I feel like a putz. Derrrrrrrr I had `@query_result_header` set to `1`